# C output question.Can anyone explain this output?

Tags: c, string, printf, output, ascii

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main()
{
    printf("%d",'AA');
}
```

I was expecting an error there but the program ran and output was 16705. Can anyone please explain this?

Comment: 'AA' is a multi character constant, which is implementation defined. Your output *16705* can vary across different compilers.

Answer (score 4):

> Can anyone please explain this?

The `'AA'` is a multi-character character constant. It has the type `int`. It's value is implementation-defined.

"Implementation" here is the compiler and your compiler has rules to which `int` value `'AA'` is mapped to. The mapping seems to be easy. Because I don't know your compiler, I am guessing it. Consult your compiler documentation to be sure.

`'AA'` maps to a value `'A' << 8 | 'A'`. Bit shifted `'A'` by a byte with another `'A'`. You system most probably uses ASCII to represent characters. The `'A'` maps in ASCII to a value `65` in decimal (`0x41` in hex). Calculating `0x41 << 8 | 0x41` gives the value of `16705` in decimal. Because this is an `int` value, you can use `%d` to print the result. So your code is equivalent to `printf("%d\n", 16705)`.

Answer (score 0):

`'AA'` is an exotic beast. It's a character literal, but ASCII does not have a single character `'AA'`. This explains why you get a non-ASCII value instead.

Answer (score -1):

this code run because the char data type is a number and you have request ho print the real number of 'AA'

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_data_types

Comment: Actually these literals are of type `int`. And what is "the real number of 'AA'" ?

Comment: Sorry for my english...
I mean that 'AA' is a number for C (of type int as you said) even if we see it as chars